# Problem with *.dynazu.com wildcard certificate... NOW --- Chrome 74 ? why

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I have WILDCARD COMODO certificate with:
CN = *.dynazu.com
and
Subject Alternative Name = DNS:*.dynazu.com, DNS:dynazu.com

I now see ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on Chrome:  74.0.3729.169
Is this normal for my laptop: laptop.dynazu.com and my production site: tracker.dynazu.com?

Or must I now have my wildcard certificates issued with all the full site names listed?  And if so, what is the purpose of a wildcard certificate?
Confused...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things change and OLD bugs show up.
I discovered that my credentials.json on the server had:

```
public static socket_url = 'https://localhost';
```

And in the past, there was no complaint. When I changed this to:

```
public static socket_url = 'https://laptop.dynazu.com';
```

all the complaints went away.  Apparently one could use a localhost connection in the past without a complaint.  And now things are more particular - which is a good thing.

So my understanding of wildcard certificates is correct and all is good..
I only report, since another may run across this issue.

Thanks to all who looked at this one.  And it is clear that in the past, I should not have been using localhost on the server for the socket communications.